# ArcPy importing error after setting path?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.4, anaconda, conda

This questions has been asked before too and I did go through most of the suggestions. Things I have tried so far: setting up correct  path variable environment, installing anaconda 32 bits, python 2.7, or even switching to python 2.7 in cmd while initially using Anaconda 3 , adding Desktop 10.4.pth file with 
following path.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.4\bin
C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.4\ArcPy
C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.4\ArcToolBox\Scripts
```

I also added those paths in environment variable

These suggestions help me to reduce the error. But Now I am getting a different error. Looks like python can find arcpy but missing another package.

Getting this error while trying to import arcpy in python 3.6.

```
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.4\ArcPy\arcpy\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from arcpy.geoprocessing import gp

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.4\ArcPy\arcpy\geoprocessing\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from _base import *

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_base'
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is in the Anaconda version that you are using. You should install Anaconda 2 (32 bit) not Anaconda 3 (32 bit). ArcGIS 10.4 works with python 2 which is 2.7 which is included in Anaconda 2. ArcGIS 10.4 does not work with Python 3.6 which is included in Anaconda 3 which you already use and stated in your question.

I am using Anaconda 2 (32 bit) and specifically Spyder and I do not have any problem in importing arcpy module. I am setting up the following path in the environment:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.4\bin
C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.4\arcpy
C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.4\ArcToolBox\Scripts
```

Also please note that in this path: `C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.4\arcpy`, arcpy should starts with small `a` and `p` not capital `A` and `P` as in your question.

Comment: @ahmadhand Paths are correct. I did installed Anaconda 2 too. But when I open spyder I call for arcpy in python 3.6. Not sure if that is the problem.

Comment: @Wisconsin I think you need to call arcpy from python 2.7. As far as I know, arcpy in ArcGIS 10.4 is not compatible with python 3.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for help. I solved my problem making following change
Rename the desktop.pth file to desktop.txt.
desktop.pth in following location
C:\Python27\ArcGISx6410.4\Lib\site-packages

I agree arcpy is working in python 2.7. Not py 3.6