# Importing ArcPy into Spyder

Tags: arcpy, spyder

I am trying to import ArcPy module into spyder and it does not work.

> import arcpy Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       import arcpy
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'arcpy'

I am using Anaconda 64 bit, Python 3.7, ArcGIS 10.3.1.

I have tried the following, nothing works:

- Downloaded Anaconda 32 bit, Python 2.7. I am not sure if have changed everything correctly though. Do I have to change anything else after I installed Anaconda 32-bit with Python 2.7?
- Change spyder Python interpreter in presettings to C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\python.exe. When I restart Spyder the console is broken.
- Add ";%PYTHON_HOME%" to my environment variables in Windows advanced system settings

What else should I try?

---

I did not see [ArcPy importing error after setting path?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/261715) before.

My problem is solved now.

The following helped:

- Installing Python Anaconda 32-bit with python 2.7 and activating python 2.7 in the Anaconda Prompt (https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/switch-environment/)
- Step 2&3 on the following page:
  https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000012334
- Adding this to my code:
  sys.path.append("C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\Lib\site-packages")
  sys.path.append(r'C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.3\arcpy')
  sys.path.append(r'C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.3\ArcToolbox\Scripts')
  sys.path.append(r'C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.3\bin')
  sys.path.append("C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\Lib")

Comment: The default Python of ArcGIS Desktop is 32-bit. You cannot get a 64-bit IDE to use that. You either need a 32-bit IDE or to install the 64-bit Background Geoprocessing (64-bit ArcPy), or ArcGIS Server (which includes a 64-bit Python) or ArcGIS Pro (ditto).

Comment: Yes, that's why i installed Anaconda 32-bit (with Python 2.7). It still couldn't import arcpy. Is there anything else that i should've changed after that? I used Spyder with Anaconda 64-bit Python 3.7 before that. By the way i forgot to mention: i installed Anaconda after arcgis was already on the computer. I read that there might be a problem with the Python interpreter or Python path, but I couldn't figure out a solution